# How to scroll Android app with Appium by Python Client

Tags: android, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I'm testing Android application and need to scroll text. I have tried everything I found here and on a Internet but nothing is working.

Appium v1.4.1 (Server v1.7.2)
Python 3.x
Using selenium webdriver

I need scroll to the bottom of a page, not to specific element

The closest is

```
self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scroll", {"direction": "up"})
```

but it is not working
.
Log is:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown mobile command "scroll". Only shell commands are supported.

Thanks

Comment: self.driver.execute_script("mobile: scroll", {"direction": "up"})
This seems the closest what I need

Answer (score 1):

For Android there are 2 good options when it takes to scrolling:

- use [TouchActions](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/)

`actions = TouchActions(driver)
el = driver.find_element_by_id(<id of element you press to start swipe>)
action.press(el).move_to(x=100, y=-1000).release().perform()`

You can also get screen size of the device to scroll more precisely:

`screen_size = driver.get_window_size()`

- use native [UiAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator.html) scrollIntoView method

`self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId("<id of scrollable view>")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId("<id of element to scroll to>"))')`

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html)